# How do I replace labels in a legend on a pie chart?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a pie chart showing the percentage of product sales from total revenue. The product names are too big, so they are abbreviated around the diagram, but in the legend the names should be full. Basically I just need to replace the labels in the legend. However, when creating a pie chart, I specify a list of labels from where the program should take them and the subsequent change of labels in the legend does not change anything.
data_names - Full names
data_names 2 - Abbreviated names
The labels=data_names command in plt.legend does not work.

[image: image pie]

```
ax.pie(data_values, labels=data_names2, colors=colors, radius=5, center=(0, 0),
     wedgeprops={"linewidth": 0.4, "edgecolor": "white"}, frame=True, rotatelabels=True)
plt.legend( 
    loc='best', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.92),labels=data_names)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this link that might be helpful.

[Legend Labels](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-add-a-legend-to-a-matplotlib-pie-chart)

Using their example, I created a simple pie chart.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [7.50, 3.50]
plt.rcParams["figure.autolayout"] = True

labels = ['Walking', 'Talking', 'Sleeping', 'Working']
abbrevs = ['Walk', 'Talk', 'Sleep', 'Work']  # Abbreviations for the legend
sizes = [23, 45, 12, 20]
colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow']

patches, texts = plt.pie(sizes, colors=colors, shadow=True, labels = labels, startangle=90)
plt.legend(patches, abbrevs, loc="best")
plt.axis('equal')

plt.show()
```

And that produced the pie chart with a legend with custom labels.

[image: Pie Chart Legend]

Comment: I copied your code completely, but the diagram seemed to me only with abbreviated labels. Picture - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ezcz4RMIj9VTzlWHcqFiIkCxITa6P2DB/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You are correct.  I had updated my answer, but I forgot one line of code that I changed.  The line "patches, texts = plt.pie(sizes, colors=colors, shadow=True, startangle=90)" is actually now "patches, texts = plt.pie(sizes, colors=colors, shadow=True, labels = labels, startangle=90)".  I will correct my answer above to show that.  Regards.

Comment: Thank you very much! But I found one problem: the command " plt.legend().get_frame().set_facecolor('black') ", which converts the legend background to black, resets labels to full names. How to fix it? I need legends on a black background

Comment: I got it to work by including the face color within the "plt.legend" function directly.  You probably want to try "plt.legend(patches, abbrevs, loc="best", facecolor='black')".  Regards.